# Is there a difference between さみしい and さびしい？

Tags: nuances, words, dialects, readings

Both mean "lonely" and appear to be valid readings for 寂しい.

Is there a difference in nuance? Is this difference due to dialect?

Comment: There's a little explanation on this answer http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/397/difference-between-and/398#398

Answer (score 23):

According to [an answer to a similar question on Goo's oshiete site](http://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/552702.html):

「さびしい」 is generally used in two ways (roughly equivalent to how the english "lonely" is used):

1. an emotional state of emptiness, isolation, or a feeling of lacking

   - Examples: 「さびしい正月を迎える」「ふところがさびしい」
2. quiet and empty of people or sounds

   - Example: 「さびしい山道」

These two meanings are essentially *subjective* and *objective*, respectively, and さびしい can be used in either. さみしい, however, generally tends much more toward the *subjective/emotional* meaning of (1).

As for whether it is dialectal, I do not believe that it is. The answer to the question linked above suggests that this b→m sound change is not limited to さびしい／さみしい alone, and cites other examples such as 煙る（けむる／けぶる）and [目を]つぶる／つむる.

**Update:** Inspired by @Axioplase's comment below, I investigated the b/m sound change, specifically regarding 「寒い」.

[Wiktionary](http://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%95%E3%82%80%E3%81%84) suggests that in fact, the origin of さむい is the same as さびしい: **さぶし**. At some point this split into さびし (which later became さびしい and subsequently さみしい), while さぶし also went on to form さぶい -- and subsequently, the modern さむい which we use today.

Unfortunately, I can't find many other (reputable) sources for the etymology of さむい.

Comment: +1 for the sound change comment - that's exactly what this is.

Comment: I think it's not only m->b, but m<->b. In a similar fashion, you also have 寒い【さぶい】. If I remember correctly, these changes are more frequent in the Kansai area than in the Kantô.

Comment: @Axioplase: Actually (and I can't find any sources to support or deny this), I would hypothesize that the "b" is the older sound, even with 寒い -- Kansai dialect seems (at least to me) to tend more toward archaic forms, after all, and a one way sound change seems more likely than both.

Comment: I also think that it's a "b->m" evolution, but don't have time to verify that.