# 寂しい pronounced さびしい and さみしい

Tags: words

I am reading a book and I saw that the word 寂しい can also be pronounced as さみしい instead of the usual さばいしい. Are there any differences when pronounced as さみしい?

Comment: This question seems to have been answered here https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1637/is-there-a-difference-between-%e3%81%95%e3%81%bf%e3%81%97%e3%81%84-and-%e3%81%95%e3%81%b3%e3%81%97%e3%81%84